# Bulk crop, change speed, volume, zoom, contrast etc Videos

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editor

I want to edit some videos in batch, i want to be able to change volume, speed, zoom, contrast, volume and also be able to crop the videos. I want to be able to adjust all the mentioned options.